# Find communities in a graph with Louvain

Tags: python, graph, igraph

I read T0.pkl that contains a directed graph created with networkx, thus I've turned that one in a igraph graph.
Next, I applied Louvain to the graph and now I've a louvain.VertexPartition.ModularityVertexPartition and I don't know how to use it

```
G0_nx = nx.read_gpickle("../snapshots_original/T0.pkl")
G0_nx_edges = list(G0_nx.edges)
G0_nx_nodes = list(G0_nx.nodes)
G0_ig = igraph.Graph(directed=True)
G0_ig.add_vertices(G0_nx_nodes)
G0_ig.add_edges(G0_nx_edges)

partition = louvain.find_partition(G0_ig, lv.ModularityVertexPartition)
```

Comment: Please provide what your expected outcome should be. Also please include a *full* [mcve] of your code, including any used import statements for reproducibility.

Answer (score 0):

First you can plot it to visualize the clustering:

```
igraph.plot(partition)
```

If you try to print it with a simple

```
print(partition)
```

you will obtain something similar to:

```
 Clustering with V elements and n clusters

 [cluster_id]: node1, node2, node3... (the nodes in the n-th cluster)
```

For example:

```
Clustering with 33 elements and 3 clusters

[0] 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
[1] 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21
[2] 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32
```

Afterwards you can access the nodes within a cluster just like using a list with the  desired cluster id as index:

```
print(partition[1])

[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21]
```

You should also check the Louvain library [docs](https://readthedocs.org/projects/louvain-igraph/downloads/pdf/latest/), where other features such as temporal community detection are outlined.